# how to append an object to a table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the tweets and the corresponding id of that user in an object `obj`. I want to append the object to a table but I get an empty table. What's the problem, please?

```
tweet_tab = []


def searchTweets(client):
    for i in users_name:
        client = getClient()
        user = client.get_user(username=i)
        userId = user.data.id
        tweets = client.get_users_tweets(userId,
                                         expansions=[
                                             'author_id', 'referenced_tweets.id', 'referenced_tweets.id.author_id',
                                             'in_reply_to_user_id', 'attachments.media_keys', 'entities.mentions.username', 'geo.place_id'],
                                         tweet_fields=[
                                             'id', 'text', 'author_id', 'created_at', 'conversation_id', 'entities',
                                             'public_metrics', 'referenced_tweets'
                                         ],
                                         user_fields=[
                                             'id', 'name', 'username', 'created_at', 'description', 'public_metrics',
                                             'verified'
                                         ],
                                         place_fields=['full_name', 'id'],
                                         media_fields=['type', 'url', 'alt_text', 'public_metrics'])
        if not tweets is None and len(tweets) > 0:
            obj = {}
            obj['id'] = userId
            obj['text'] = tweets
            tweet_tab.append(obj)
        return tweet_tab


print("tableau final", tweet_tab)
```

Comment: Are you actually calling ``searchTweets()``?

Comment: You "return" in the first iteration of the for-loop. If there are no tweets for the first user name the table is empty.

Comment: yes I am calling it ```searchTweets(client)``` @saquintes

Comment: Should I return tweet_tab after iterating over all users?@Michael Butscher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem looks like it's already solved, as Michael pointed out it's missplaced `return` statement but I would like to give you one hint that can help you eluding such problems in future. Good programming habits say that (if possible) body of loop should be in different function. That way we won't have a problem with bad placed return, look:

```
def searchTweet(username):
    client = getClient()
    user = client.get_user(username=username)
    userId = user.data.id
    tweets = client.get_users_tweets(...)
    if not tweets: # it works because empty list evaluates to False
        return None
    return {"id": userId, "text": tweets}


def searchTweets():
    tweet_tab = []
    for i in users_name:
        res = searchTweet(username=i)
        if res is not None:
            tweet_tab.append(res)
    return tweet_tab
```

Or even with python list comprehesion

```
def searchTweets():
    res = [searchTweet(username) for username in users_name]
    return [el for el in res if el is not None]
```

With using of [cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) decorator you can call this function many times to get that list which will be calculated only once.

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def searchTweets():
    res = [searchTweet(username) for username in users_name]
    return [el for el in res if el is not None]
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. 
just a question regarding what you wrote: When I place tweet_tab inside the function then I will not be able in other functions because it is not global anymore. Is that true? i wanna be able to use the content of that table as input for other functions

Comment: that's right, but probably if you need it as global there is something bad with code - notice that if you need run process once, you can store result of searchTweets in variable `res = searchTweets()` and then  `my_next_function(res)` Or you can use cache decorator so result will be calculated once and store in program memory docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache

Comment: Glad could help! Do not forget to upvote and approve answer if solution works for you, to let us know more help is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change
`if not tweets is None and len(tweets) > 0` to

`if tweets is not None and len(tweets) > 0` or

`if tweets and len(tweets) > 0`

Comment: same problem. When I print the table inside the function I get the wished result but the global variable stays empty